# Select only one in dynamic radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is possible to select only one radio button using a same name? I want to select only one radio button in every question.

The problem is it only selects one radio button in all appended html elements.

DEFAULT HMTL:

```
//question 1
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][]" value="2">
```

ADDED HTML ELEMENTS USING JAVASCRIPT APPEND:

```
//question 2
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][]" value="3">
```

Comment: Then you have to give different names to different questions. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/gjpgakev/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only select one radio button in a group, and all the buttons with the same name are part of the same group. You should use a different name for the answers to each question. In your example, you can put the question number in the array index.

```
//question 1
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][1]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][1]" value="2">

//question 2
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][2]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][2]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="fields[my_cb][2]" value="3">
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a radio button in a button group to checked by default you use: `checked="checked"`

In order to have multiple button groups you need to name each group differently:

```
//question 1
<input type="radio" name="grp1" value="1" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="grp1" value="2">

//question 2
<input type="radio" name="grp2" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="grp2" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="grp2" value="3">
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question about checking a button by default.

Comment: @Barmar no, I had answered it and then immediately edited it to do more explaining, just took to long to type i guess. The OP asked how to select one in each group of questions.

Comment: I believe him about that part. But the question is about allowing the user to select one answer in each group, not about selecting anything by default.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I may have misunderstood right off the bat but he does say select only one in each question so I thought he meant select each by default, but no harm in giving him more than he needs because that question will come up next I guarantee it.